# Delete a character from second last line in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

How can we remove character from second last line of a file in unix?

For example I have a file with content as follows:

```
aaa
bbb*
ccc*
ddd*
eee
```

my output should be :

```
aaa
bbb*
ccc*
ddd
eee
```

any ideas on this?

Answer (score 5):

The generic way to do this in a single pass with sed is to use a sliding window, similar to what is described in the [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/tail.html).

As you are only interested in a substitution on the second to last line there is no need for hold space. In this case a single `N` will suffice:

```
sed 'N; $! { P; D; }; s/.\n/\n/'
```

Or as a BSD sed compatible script:

```
sed 'N; $! { P; D; }; s/.\n/\
/'
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb*
ccc*
ddd
eee
```

*Explanation*

- The `N` command adds a second line to pattern space.
- The `$!` block is evaluated when we have not reached the last line.
- `{ P; D; }` prints the first line of pattern space and deletes it. The `D` has a side-effect of restarting the script if pattern space is not empty.
- The substitution command is only evaluated when the last two lines are in pattern space.

Comment: Since the substitution only takes place on encountering the last line a perhaps more positive take might be `sed '$!N;$s/.\(\n\)/\1/;P;D' file`

Comment: @potong: yes that makes it more explicit, but for a short script like this I prefer having the command run last at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are three general approaches that spring to mind.

Use `wc -l file` to get the number of lines:

```
awk 'NR==n-1{sub(/.$/,"")}1' n=$(wc -l file)
aaa
bbb*
ccc*
ddd
eee
```

Parse the file twice:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{n++;next}FNR==n-1{sub(/.$/,"")}1' file file
aaa
bbb*
ccc*
ddd
eee
```

Reverse the file before and after processing:

```
tac file | sed '2s/.$//' | tac
aaa
bbb*
ccc*
ddd
eee
```

Answer (score 2):

nice time to re-use `ed`, for once :

the short version:

```
{ echo '$-1s/.$//' ; echo "w" ; } | ed file_to_modify.txt >/dev/null
```

version with some "debugging info" ^^ :

```
{ echo 'doing: $-1s/.$//' >&2 ; echo '$-1s/.$//' ; echo "doing: w" >&2 ; echo "w" ; echo "C" >&2 ; } | ed file_to_modify.txt
```

in a nutshell : `ed` is very close to vi, but works on 1 line at a time...
I just tell it to 's/.$//' (replace last char of a line by nothing) on the n-1th line ($= last line in ed, and $-1 = last line - 1)

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with **vi** or **vim** or any editor and edit the file like you want

Comment: if vim is an option, this question should not exist at all! what about if OP needs it in a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

straightforward with awk:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){if(i==NR-1)sub(/.$/,"",a[i]);print a[i]}}' file
```

a bit tricky way with awk:

```
awk '{if(f>1)print p;p=l;f++;l=$0}END{sub(/.$/,"",p);print p;print l}' file
```